# IntelliJ debugger thinks that my Stack is actually one element smaller than it is?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stack

I am trying to calculate the sum of all the elements in a stack without modifying the original stack. To do this, I am popping the items off the original and pushing them into a new stack so I can keep an unmodified copy. As the items are popped/pushed, I add the sums by peeking at the top of the new stack.

This is working fine but I have a very confusing problem with the stack size when testing the method out.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<>();
    myStack.push(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(3);
    myStack.push(4);
    myStack.push(5);
    System.out.println("Stack size = " + myStack.size());
    System.out.println(stackSum(myStack));
}

private static int stackSum(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    int sum = 0;
    Stack<Integer> newStack = new Stack<>();
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= stack.size(); i++) {
            newStack.push(stack.pop());
            sum += newStack.peek();
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I am getting the answer 12 instead of 15 and this is because IntelliJ thinks that the length of the stack being passed to the stackSum() method is 4 and not 5. Here is a pic:

[image: Picture of IntelliJ debugger and output]

the SOUT clearly says the size is 5 but the debugger thinks it's 4?!

Would really appreciate a bit of help understanding what's going on here. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
private static int stackSum(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    int sum = 0;
    int n = stack.size();
    Stack<Integer> newStack = new Stack<>();
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            newStack.push(stack.pop());
            sum += newStack.peek();
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

That works how I expected. I had to keep a copy of the stack as part of the spec. This is fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger states `size = 4` because you already performed a `stack.pop` call removing one element from the stack, therefore its size is 4 by now.

You should drop `if` and `for` and replace it with a `while(!stack.isEmpty())` instead and probably eliminate `newStack` as well:

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    sum += stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Also just seen a bug in the code where i <= stack.size(). As the items are popped off the stack its reducing the size so the loop isn't completing as I'd expect. Back to the drawing board a bit I think

Comment: @PumpkinBreath yes, it almost always is a bad idea iterating over any collection while manipulating its contents. Anyway my `while` loop should do everything you need.